# confused with CS0246: The Type or Namespace Name <Type/Namespace> Could Not be Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I know many people have asked versions of this question, but nothing I try works

I am new to using visual studio 2010 web developer. But have a couple of issues I can not resolve.

My first problem is
CS0246: The Type or Namespace Name  Could Not be Found

I have entered "Using with my namespace name.
and I have also created a dll so I could add it as a reference with out any luck.

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using GDIDAL;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds;
        ds = GDIDAL.GDItest.Get_BraeburnRisk("GDI.PUB.Grower");

        DataTable myDataTable = ds.Tables[0];

        // foreach loop to get each DataRow of DataTable retrieved from DataSet   

        foreach (DataRow dRow in myDataTable.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {

                Response.Write(dRow[i] + ", ");
            }
            Response.Write("<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

The code is simple as it is a testapp to prove we can get it working.
From what I have seen on the net this should have resolve the problem.
I also find that if I run the code in DEbug mode from within VS2010 Web Developer it works. The error only occurs when I deploy to the web server.

The second error I have found while trying to fix the above problem is
 warning : The following assembly has dependencies on a version of the .NET Framework that is higher than the target and might not load correctly during runtime causing a failure: GDIDAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. The dependencies are: mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089. You should either ensure that the dependent assembly is correct for the target framework, or ensure that the target framework you are addressing is that of the dependent assembly.

Now from what I have read to fix this errors everything I have created if targeted for .net 4.0 so I very unsure on where to go with this.

Comment: Have you tried to fully qualify your classes with the Namespace Name instead of `using`?

Comment: Yes, without any success

Comment: I have also tried adding the namespace in the web.config file this only generates a second error for the same thing, but pointing to the web.config file

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="GDIDAL"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>

Comment: Is .net 4.0 installed on the server?

Comment: Yes .net 4.0 is installed on the server.

But I still can not get it to work